# How to show a hidden element if a specific child exists CSS only

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

**Question (2018):** Is there any CSS construct that would hide divs using a selector and then unhide one containing a specific selector?

---

I was marking this a a dupe

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53209121/css-selector-if-a-container-is-empty-display-none

Code would be

```css
div { border: 1px solid black; text-align:center; width:400px }
div[id*="accordion_prop_floor_plans"]:empty { display:none }
```

```html
<div id="accordion_prop_floor_plans_1"></div>
<div id="accordion_prop_floor_plans_2"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150&text=image" title="image here" /><br/>Plan 2</div>
<div id="accordion_prop_floor_plans_3"></div>
```

Then I realised that there might be another use case.

**Hide divs that do not have a certain element. Or show divs that do.**

I tried `:has()`, based on [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

**but it does not work yet in any browser as of 2018**

```css
div { border: 1px solid black; text-align:center; width:400px }
div[id*="accordion_prop_floor_plans"] { display:none }
div[id*="accordion_prop_floor_plans"]:has(> img) { display:block }
```

```html
<div id="accordion_prop_floor_plans_1">Plan 1</div>
<div id="accordion_prop_floor_plans_2"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150&text=image" title="image here" /><br/>Plan 2</div>
<div id="accordion_prop_floor_plans_3">Plan 3</div>
```

I can do it in JS easily:

```js
document.querySelector('div[id*="accordion_prop_floor_plans"]>img').parentNode.style.display="block";
```

```css
div { border: 1px solid black; text-align:center; width:400px }
div[id*="accordion_prop_floor_plans"] { display:none }
```

```html
<div id="accordion_prop_floor_plans_1">Plan 1</div>
<div id="accordion_prop_floor_plans_2"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150&text=image" title="image here" /><br/>Plan 2</div>
<div id="accordion_prop_floor_plans_3">Plan 3</div>
```

Comment: yes only the JS works, there is still no CSS solution. Even in 2019 I don't think there will be one. Probably the `:has()` selector will have more support.

Answer (score 2):

As I commented, there is still no CSS solution for such situation since it's closely related to the existence of [a parent selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector).

By the way, we can still use some **specific** workarounds in order to show/hide some elements:

Here is an example for this particular case:

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
  width: 400px
}

div[id*="accordion_prop_floor_plans"] {
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  background:
    linear-gradient(#000,#000) top/100% 1px,
    linear-gradient(#000,#000) bottom/100% 1px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  border-right:1px solid;
  border-left:1px solid;
}
div[id*="accordion_prop_floor_plans"] img {
  margin-top:2px;
  margin-bottom:30px;
}
div[id*="accordion_prop_floor_plans"] > div {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="accordion_prop_floor_plans_1">
  <div>Plan 1</div>
</div>
<div id="accordion_prop_floor_plans_2">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150&text=image" title="image here" />
  <div>Plan 2</div>
</div>
<div id="accordion_prop_floor_plans_3">
  <div>Plan 3</div>
</div>
```

The idea is to make the text out of the flow and in case there is an image the container will have a height and we will see the text with it. If there is no image, we won't see the text. I also replaced border-top/bottom with gradient to avoid seeing them for the hidden elements.

This remain a *hacky* solution for this particular case.

Comment: @mplungjan removed and updated my solution to add the borders (and I am not the downvoter)