# HIde Parent div if child div is empty using css

Tags: html, css

I want to hide `bannerbox` div if `banner-description` is empty

```
<div class="bannerbox">
<div class="banner-description">If Empty then Hide</div>
</div>
```

I tried few thing but didn't work

> .banner-description:blank{display:none}

This hide the child

I am looking for solution in CSS if possible

Comment: if it's empty then when hide it?

Comment: @TemaniAfif, I need to hide parent div if child div is empty

Comment: This is not possible in pure CSS as it can't select parents of elements

Comment: did you try javascript ?

Comment: yes I understand this, considering your code, if the child is empty then the parent is also empty, so you will see nothing (unless you are hidding more code to us)

Comment: @TemaniAfif The parent could have any number of styles applied that make it visible when empty.

Comment: It was easy with Jquery i cant use JS or Jquery need to find solution with CSS

Comment: @Learning There is no solution with CSS.

Comment: @Roy Since `.bannerbox` has a child element `:empty` would not work.

Comment: @Turnip something we don't see here, he should add more context about this as it may be an XY problem and he's tackling the problem in a wrong way. Probably he don't even need to target a parent element which is impossible.

Comment: @TemaniAfif, This is simple there is no other context to it i simple have to hide parent div if child div is empty. If there was more to it i would have definitely added more details and fiddle example. Is this duplicate question

Comment: in this case you cannot, as there is no way to target an parent element based on child state thus the duplicate

Comment: @TemaniAfif, thank you.. so only solution is using JS

Comment: @Turnip here is an example of situation where I hide a parent element based on childs https://stackoverflow.com/q/53209544/8620333 without the need of parent selector because it's a particular case with specific CSS. So the generic answer is "no" but with more context we can handle this differently.

Comment: @Learning yes actually you need JS for this.

Answer (score -4):

This can not be achieved via css, you can use JS/jQuery like following code

```
if($('.banner-description').html()==''){
 $('.bannerbox').hide();
}
```

Hope this will work.